# VisionOS Support for Mixing Swift and C++ Interoperability

Tags: c++, swift, xcode, language-interoperability, visionos

I'm exploring the possibilities of mixing Swift and C++ for a project that involves VisionOS. The Swift official documentation on Mixing Swift and C++ mentions that C++ interoperability is supported for development and deployment on all platforms that Swift supports.

I would like to confirm whether this support extends to VisionOS. Does VisionOS allow the use of C++ APIs, and how can various C++ APIs be effectively imported and used in Swift for VisionOS development?

If anyone has experience or insights related to mixing Swift and C++ specifically for VisionOS, I would greatly appreciate your guidance and advice.

Thank you for your assistance.

I've started working on a project involving VisionOS, and I wanted to leverage the capabilities of C++ to enhance certain aspects of my application.

My expectation was to successfully integrate C++ components into my VisionOS project and utilize the capabilities of C++ to enhance certain features and performance aspects. I was hoping to find a seamless way to import and use C++ APIs within Swift, enabling me to achieve my project's objectives efficiently and effectively.

Answer (score 1):

visionOS is iOS-based and supports nearly all the same features of iOS, similar to iPadOS, and the more limited tvOS. Regarding direct C++ interoperability, this newer feature was introduced to Swift, which is supported across all Apple platforms (including visionOS).

I would refer to [this year's WWDC session and its included resources about this](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10172/). Along with the video, it also includes code samples and more documentation, all of which can be implemented on visionOS as well.

Comment: May be I am doing something wrong, but the below code snippet from the official swift doc is working fine when the run destination is set to Mac, but when I change the run destination to Apple Vision Pro, it doesn't compile and throws some errors.

let cxxString = std.string("This is a C++ string")
let swiftString = String(cxxString)
No exact matches in call to initializer

So, what I get from this is that the mixing Swift and C++ doesn't support visionOS for now.